# How do I call a dependent dropdown function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two dropdown-select of categories and sub-categories. I want to be able to fetch values using the id of the parent dropdown. Here's the code below

```
const Form = () => {
    
  
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([])
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
  const [subCategory,  setSubCategory] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSubCategory, setSelectedSubCategory] = useState("");
  
  


  const getCategory = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const fetchCategory = await Axios.post("apiEndpoint/sectors");    
      const item = Object.keys(fetchCategory.data);
      setCategory(item);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);



//API for subCategory https://apiEndpoint/category/<categoryID>

  const handleSubCategory = useCallback(async (e) => {
    const curr = e.target.value
    setSelectedCategory(curr)
    try {
      const fetch = await Axios.post(`https://apiEndpoint/category/${curr}`);
      const result = Object.keys(fetch.data);
      console.log(result)
      //setSubCategory

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  

  useEffect(() => {
    getCategory()
   
  }, [getCategory]);


  return (
    <div className="form-container">
     
          <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            <div className="textfield">
              <TextField
                className="box"
                select
                required
                label="Category"
                SelectProps={{
                  native: true,
                }}
                sx={{
                  width: "23ch",
                }}
                value={selectedCategory}
                onChange={handleSubCategory}
              >
                 <option value="">Select Category</option>
                {category?.map((val) => (
                  <option key={val} value={val}>
                    {val}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </TextField>

              <TextField
                className="box"
                select
                required
                label="Sub-Category"
                SelectProps={{
                  native: true,
                }}
                sx={{
                  width: "23ch",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setSelectedSubCategory(e.target.value)}
                value={selectedSubCategory}
              >
                <option value="">Select Sub-Category</option>
                {subCategory?.map((options) => (
                  <option key={options} value={options}>
                    {options}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </TextField>

             
            </div>
            
          </form>
       
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

The category API values are the id for each category which should be used to fetch a subcategory list for a selected category. The above code is what I've tried but I guess this not the approach.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing ? is it the sub categories not being fetched ? or not being displayed on ui ?

Comment: `https://pshs3.herokuapp.com/category/${curr}` this call returns rest of the first drop down options  as the result. is it intended?

Comment: @HritikSharma The category API returns list of categories with their id in a key - value pair. The keys are the categories name while the values are the id. for the sub-categories, the var in the API is the category id. so when i select a category in a dropdown, the corresponding subcategory list should display...

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera No.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useEffect that call the subCategory everytime the selectedCategory changes

```js
const Form = () => {
    
  
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([])
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
  const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState(false);
  const [subCategory,  setSubCategory] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSubCategory, setSelectedSubCategory] = useState("");
  

  useEffect(() => {
  (async function loadData() {
      await getCategory() 
    })();
    
  }, []);
  
   useEffect(() => {
    if(selectedCategory !== ""){
     (async function loadData() {
      await getSubCategory(selectedCategory);
    })();
    } 
  }, [selectedCategory]);

  const getCategory = async () => {
    try {
      const fetchCategory = await Axios.post("https://pshs3.herokuapp.com/sectors");    
      const item = Object.keys(fetchCategory.data);
      setCategory(item);
      if(fetchError) setFetchError(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setFetchError(true);
    }
  }

  const getSubCategory = async (current) => {
    try {
      const fetch = await Axios.post(`https://pshs3.herokuapp.com/category/${current}`);
  const result = Object.keys(fetch.data);
      setSubCategory(item);
      if(fetchError) setFetchError(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setFetchError(true);
    }
  }
  
  const handleSubCategory = () => {
    const curr = e.target.value
    setSelectedCategory(curr) 
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
     
          <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            <div className="textfield">
              <TextField
                className="box"
                select
                required
                label="Category"
                SelectProps={{
                  native: true,
                }}
                sx={{
                  width: "23ch",
                }}
                value={selectedCategory}
                onChange={handleSubCategory}
              >
                 <option value="">Select Category</option>
                {category?.map((val) => (
                  <option key={val} value={val}>
                    {val}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </TextField>

              <TextField
                className="box"
                select
                required
                label="Sub-Category"
                SelectProps={{
                  native: true,
                }}
                sx={{
                  width: "23ch",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setSelectedSubCategory(e.target.value)}
                value={selectedSubCategory}
              >
                <option value="">Select Sub-Category</option>
                {subCategory?.map((options) => (
                  <option key={options} value={options}>
                    {options}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </TextField>

             
            </div>
            
          </form>
       
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but that didnt work.

Comment: do you get error or what's the output ?

Comment: I forget to await functions inside the two useEffect , you can add it and retest please ?

Comment: When a category is selected, the subcategories dropdown returned the other categories not selected. weird

Comment: i updated the solution should work now